# show data for each kind of user yii

Tags: yii, rights

i am newby on yii.

I am using user and rigths yii extension.
I have create model and views using gii. 
Each user belongs to an a domain

```
+----------------+  
|      users     |
|----------------|
| id             |
| username       |
|  ...           |
| id_from        |
+----------------+

+----------------+  
|      from      |
|----------------|
| id             |
| desc           |
+----------------+

+----------------+  
|      data      |
|----------------|
| id_user        |
| data_1         |
| data_2         |
| ......         |
+----------------+
```

besides of the roll of each user. 
when I use the created views, each user can see all data but I need that each user see only their own data. How could I do it?

is like put a filter or somthing like that for each kind of user.

thx in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$model = Data::model()->findallbyattributes(array('id_user'=>Yii::app()->user->id));
$this->render('yourviewfile', array('model'=>$model));
```

and then in your view file

```
foreach($model as $m){
  echo $m['data_1'].','.$m['data_2'];
}
```